# How to create "Embossed" effect on a text in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics

I wanted to create "**Embossed**" text effect on a text in a UILabel. I am not able to choose a right option. Please guide me on how to implement this with the right available options. Do i need to use **CoreGraphics or CoreText or Customized UILabel**?. I just want the way how numbers appear on a Credit Card.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
[label setShadowColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
[label setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, -1)];
```

You can tweak this to get the desired effect.

Comment: Embossing and droping shadows are two different effects.

Answer (score 0):

UILabel's `shadowColor` and `shadowOffset` offer a limited customisation. You could also override UILabel's `drawRect:`

```
-(void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ref = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(ref, CGSizeMake(0.0, 2.0), 3.0, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    [super drawTextInRect:rect];
}
```

Comment: This requires subclassing UILabel again?

Comment: @PradeepReddyKypa, Yes. You need to subclass UILabel to do that. A shadow property is already available in UILabel so that you dont have to subclass again.